# Night Shift Hours Calculation

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need a formula that can calculate night shift hours.

Shift Start time 13:00 and End time 22:00, shift hours to be calculated once time passed 18:00 till Time out.

[image]

Comment: MJ... I used to watch the Chicago Bulls play all the time back in the day... See if this helps you figure it out some more... https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/06/24/calculate-time-excel/

Comment: `=EndTime - TimeValue(18,0,0)`

Comment: Will night shift ever work past midnight?

Answer (score 1):

Calculating shift time when `Time In` and `Time Out` are in the same day is easy as all you have to do is take `Time In` from `Time Out`.  When you are calculating night shift hours where you are working past midnight, it is a little different.

Excel calculates time in proportions of 24 hours.  You can see this if you select a cell, format it as custom number format `hh:mm`, type in `12:00` and then format it back to `General`.

You will see `0.5` because 12:00 is half of 24 hours.  Therefore midnight (00:00) the following day would be equal to `1`.

Now for the following, I am assuming the screenshot cutting you provided has the columns arranged from excel columns `A` to `L` and the rows are `1` and `2`.

If `Time Out` (cell `D2`) is in the day following `Time In` (cell `C2`), to get the total shift time you would need to enter a formula to calculate **(1 - Time In) + Time Out** which is `Time In` until midnight plus the rest of the shift past midnight.

For total shift time `=(1-C2)+D2`

I am a little confused with what you are after when you are stipulating `Time In` to be `13:00`, `Time Out` to be `22:00` and `Shift Hours` to be time past `18:00`.

13:00 to 18:00 is 5 hours (calculated with `=(18/24)-Time In`)

If you are looking for `18:00` to `Time Out` and `Time Out` is past midnight, then the time passed would be `=((1-(18/24))+Time Out)`

If you are looking for `18:00` to `Time Out` and `Time Out` is in the same day as `18:00`, then it's simple.  The time passed would be `=Time Out-(18/24)`